# Webform i18n doesn't work

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

We have installed and enabled:

- Webform 7.x-4.0-alpha6
- Webform Localization 7.x-4.x-dev
- Internationalization 7.x-1.7

We have created several webforms (in English).

When I look `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` and select "Limit search to" to "Webform Localization", I see an empty list of strings to be translated.

This way we are unable to translate our webforms. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Need to refresh in `admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string`.